# How can I use strokeBorder for trimmed Shapes?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have difficulty to use strokeBorder after trim in SwiftUI, how can do this?

```
Circle()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
  .strokeBorder(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 50.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
```

Error:

> Value of type 'some Shape' has no member 'strokeBorder'

⚠️ There are at least 2 other ways to get the result like `strokeBorder` gives. But they are **NOT** using `strokeBorder`, I want to solve the issue while using `strokeBorder`.

Comment: I usually just do a `.stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)` + `.padding(2.5)` (inset by half of the line width)

Comment: Nice one @aheze, I find (at least on iOS 16.1) that if you use `strokeBorder` then the circle takes up as much space as it can, in all dimensions, but with `stroke` it doesn't, it remains square.

Comment: @CMash odd, could be a bug.

Comment: Why are insist on using `strokeBorder` when they are other ways to achieve something exactly looks like the same?

Answer (score 0):

This still seems to be a problem, so maybe it's not a bug to be fixed. I used the same solution suggested by aheze, but having the lineWidth as a variable or constant helps, especially if there are additional layers that need to be added. For instance, any additional Shapes/Images that need to layered on top would also need to have this additional padding to keep things aligned.

```
let lineWidth: CGFloat = 50.0

Circle()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
  .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
  .padding(lineWidth / 2)
```

Comment: As it is already in the question, you can't use `.strokeBorder`.
@Aheze suggested `.stroke`.

Comment: Thanks, I meant to use `.stroke`. I updated my answer. I know he specifically wants to use `.strokeBorder` but considering the bug (if it is a bug) is still present almost 2 years later, I think it's good to have an example code without a hard-coded lineWidth. The let can be an `@State` or `@Binding' if it needs to be more dynamic.